# Error:Your project does not own Dynamic Links domain, while creating dynamic link in swift using firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I am using firebase for creating dynamic link, I followed documents [url1](https://www.raywenderlich.com/21376846-firebase-dynamic-links-getting-started)

and [url2](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/ios/create)

and try to create dynamic link but showing an error

> The operation couldn’t be completed. Your project does not own Dynamic
> Links domain

My code is:-

```
 var components = URLComponents()
    components.scheme = "https"
    components.host = "google.com"
    components.path = "/about"
    
    let itemIDQueryItem = URLQueryItem(name: "postID", value:"002")
    components.queryItems = [itemIDQueryItem]
    guard let linkParameter = components.url else { return }
    print("I am sharing \(linkParameter.absoluteString)")
    
    
    
    let linking = "https://xyz.page.link"
    
    let linkBuilder = DynamicLinkComponents(link: linkParameter, domainURIPrefix: linking)
    if let myBundleId = Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier {
        linkBuilder?.iOSParameters = DynamicLinkIOSParameters(bundleID: myBundleId)
    }
    linkBuilder?.iOSParameters?.appStoreID = "964608"
    linkBuilder?.socialMetaTagParameters = DynamicLinkSocialMetaTagParameters()
    linkBuilder?.socialMetaTagParameters?.title = "demno"
    linkBuilder?.socialMetaTagParameters?.descriptionText = "demo demo"
    linkBuilder?.socialMetaTagParameters?.imageURL = URL(string: """
      https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/\
      1381909139345969153/tkgxJB3i_400x400.jpg
      """)!
    
    print(linkBuilder?.url)
      linkBuilder?.shorten() { url, warnings, error in
      guard let url = url, error != nil else { return }
      print("The short URL is: \(url)")
    }
```

I also added associated domains:

> applinks:xyz.page.link

URL Schemes: - https://xyz.page.link

Kindly help me Thanks

Comment: have you tried with linkBuilder?.iOSParameters!.minimumAppVersion = "1.0"?

Comment: And I suggest you to don't create components, just use  https://google.com/about directly in link parameter of DynamicLinkComponents.

Comment: hi @JigneshMayani thanks for reply, I tried both , but no luck

Comment: at which place are you getting an error?... while shorten() ?

Comment: @JigneshMayani, yes

Comment: @JigneshMayani long url is created successfully, but showing error on it also while debugging using &d=1 , don't know what is going on

Comment: have you checked that your dynamic link url prefix is working?... check by this https://example.com/apple-app-site-association link and please replace https://example.com by your URL prefix.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234891/discussion-between-jignesh-mayani-and-user3120670).